# Spring Integration poller hangs or stop after a while

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have an application which reads JMS message coming from a HornetQ.

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
            id="myJmsChannelAdapter"
            channel="myJmsChannel"
            connection-factory="myCredentialsConnectionFactory"
            destination-name="${my.jms.topic}"
            pub-sub-domain="true"
            subscription-durable="${my.jms.subscription.durable}"
            client-id="${my.jms.client.id}"
            durable-subscription-name="${my.jms.subscription.name}"
            />
```

When a message arrive, I treat them via a poller

```
<!-- Send Jms message one by one to creation -->
<int:bridge input-channel="myJmsChannel" output-channel="jmsMessageCreateInputChannel">
    <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="1" fixed-delay="100">
        <int:transactional transaction-manager="transactionManager" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW"/>
    </int:poller>
</int:bridge>
```

The poller call a chain which store the content of the message in my DB

```
<chain id="jmsMessageCreate" input-channel="jmsMessageCreateInputChannel">
    <!-- extract the operation from the message itself -->
    <int-xml:xpath-header-enricher>
        <int-xml:header name="operation" xpath-expression="name(./node())" overwrite="true"/>
    </int-xml:xpath-header-enricher>

    <service-activator expression="@jmsMessageService.createNewJmsMessage(payload, headers['operation'])"/>
    <!-- have a JPA entity in the payload -->
    <gateway request-channel="persistEntityChannel"/>
    <logging-channel-adapter logger-name="JmsLogger" expression="'JMS message with operation ['+headers['operation']+'] created in DB'"/>
</chain>
```

My problem is the following, sometimes, for no apparent reason and without any error message in the logs, my messages are no treated anymore. The chain id jmsMessageCreate is not called anymore like if the poller stopped working.
If the server is restarted, it works well again but I have lost the JMS messages that were sent between the moment the poller stopped and the moment the server is restarted.

I really don't know where to look or what to do to prevent that. Maybe a change in the config?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: could this be a heap issue? faced it one... inspect the app using visualvm or similar..

Comment: You should never use a queue channel and poller with a message-driven adapter - see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the poller thread is "stuck" somewhere in your code. Use `jstack <pid>` to take a thread dump to see what the thread is doing. You can use `jps` to find the pid.

To avoid losing messages you should set `acknowledge="transacted"` on the message-driven adapter - this was changed to default to `true` in version 4.2.

You should not be using QueueChannels and pollers in this environment - the threading is managed by the message-driven adapter. With a queue channel, even with transacted sessions, the container will commit as soon as the message is put in the queue.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I removed the poller and set the acknowledge option as you advised. Everything seems to run smoothly on my local environment.
The problem occured in a production environment where I cannot access unfortunately so I cannot run a jstack :( I'll see if it happens again.

Comment: @gary russel: What should I look for in jstack? Which state indicates that the poller is stuck?

Comment: It's hard to say; it could be many things - reading from a socket, a deadlock, etc, etc. Bear in mind as well that a stack trace is just a snapshot at an instant in time so sometimes taking several back-to-back and comparing them will help. You can also use tools like this https://jstack.review/#tda_1_dump to help look for deadlocks etc.